# Find a CSL style that shows a particular field?

Tags: pandoc, csl, pandoc-citeproc

This question was originally on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/688515/how-to-find-a-style-that-displays-an-unusual-text-field/688517?noredirect=1#comment1708279_688517, but since it involves Pandoc and not biblatex, I was advised to ask it here instead.

I have a biblatex file produced automatically by R that contains citations for R packages.  This is part of a bookdown project, but to make it easily reproducible I extracted plain Markdown and have included that below.

This is one of the entries in the `packages.bib` file that was automatically produced:

```
@Manual{R-tables,
  title = {tables: Formula-Driven Table Generation},
  author = {Duncan Murdoch},
  note = {R package version 0.9.21},
  url = {https://dmurdoch.github.io/tables/},
  year = {2023},
}
```

I would like the reference list using this to include all of the fields, but so far all the CSL styles I've tried skip the `note`, so I get something like

> Murdoch, Duncan. 2023. *Tables: Formula-Driven Table Generation.* https://dmurdoch.github.io/tables/.

when I would like it to look like

> Murdoch, Duncan. 2023. *Tables: Formula-Driven Table Generation.* R package version 0.9.21.  https://dmurdoch.github.io/tables/.

Can anyone suggest how to find CSL styles that display the `note` like that?

I've found a solution that's good enough as a workaround, but I'm still interested in the answer to my question above. The workaround is to change `note` to `edition`, and then the display looks okay to me. But how would I search for styles showing a particular field next time this comes up?

As I already mentioned, the original document was written in `bookdown`, but I've simplified it to plain Markdown.  Put the text below into `test.md`:

```
---
bibliography: packages.bib
---

## The citation

This is a citation of the *tables* package [@R-tables].

## References
```

and the .bib entry above into `packages.bib`, then run

```
pandoc test.md --output test.html --citeproc
```

and you should get output that looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

How would I find a CSL style that would display the `note`?

Comment: Maybe try https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc/issues/180#issuecomment-145879687

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: thanks!  For others:  that gives instructions for modifying a style to handle `note`.  It's a better solution than my current workaround of changing `note` to `edition`, because some references might actually include both.